# Mind-bogling GRE equivalence

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

GRE gap equivalence from my textbook:

> If good taste has __________ the vampire genre tired and trite, the
> entertainment industry surely is not listening: for every bloodsucker
> baring fangs there is a hack baring some script.
>
> found, deemed, expected, discovered, demeaned, anticipated

For my answer, I would choose (easily I would say?) `found` and `deemed`.

But my issue is elsewhere: can somebody decode that sentence for me? (I have made no mistake in the sentence, it's exactly with these commas, with these spellings on words that the sentence reads on my textbook...) Especially after the colon, I clearly have no understanding what's going on whatsoever, but even how the sentence as a whole fits together is weird for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It starts with a condition, but the sense here is more like "Even though" than "if...then".

> Even though vampires are old fashioned and there are already lots of vampire films etc,  people in the entertainment industry ignore this and make lots of vampire stories.

The literal meaning of the second part is a bit odd (the writer didn't quite think it through) but it probably meant to suggest:

> (there are lots of vampires in movies. These vampires are "bloodsuckers baring fangs (exposing teeth)" But in Hollywood there are as many hacks (bad writers) bearing (holding) a script (that the hack has written) about vampires.

Here there is a spelling error in the original.  The intended pun is "baring fangs" and "bearing some script".  Unfortunately, at some point, the spelling has been changed and the pun has been lost.  The grammar in the second part is a bit forced to make the pun, so the spelling error is really bad.

Comment: I took the second _baring_ to be a deliberate metaphor: "revealing to the world".

Comment: Nobody says "baring a script", you don't reveal scripts, you carry them around trying to sell them to producers, you show them to everyone all the time -- its almost a trope.  You bear scripts, you don't bare scripts.